# Multiple large MySQL SELECT queries - better to run in parallel or in a queue?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization

I have looked up answers to this question a bunch and couldn't find a specific answer - sorry in advance if I missed something! Also, I'm a SQL optimization noob.

I have an analytics dashboard which pulls data based on users' requests from a large database.

Each page the user loads runs a number of different queries to populate different parts of the page (different charts, tables, etc). Some of these pages can take quite some time to load as the user might request several years of data.

Currently, each part of the page pings off one SELECT query to the SQL server but as there are several parts of the page, those queries end up running in parallel.

Would it be faster to run these queries in a queue - to allow the server to process one query at a time? Or to keep everything in parallel, as is?

The added benefit of running them one at a time is that we could run the queries to fill in the "above-the-fold" part of the page first...

Hope that all makes sense and take it easy on me please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also say "it depends", but I lean toward parallelism.

- Probably should not have more parallelism than the number of CPU cores.
- I rarely see a system that chews up all the CPU cores -- unless it does not have good enough indexes.  That is, fix the indexes before asking the question.
- If the data is bigger than can be cached, it *may* be faster to queue, since you *may* have a choke point -- I/O.
- If the table(s) are continually being changed, turn off the Query Cache.
- Is your goal to get *some* results on the page early (a likely Human Interface goal), add a small delay in all but one AJAX callee (not caller).
- If multiple pages could be computing at the same time, things get more complex.  For example, you can't really control the parallelism.

Let's see the queries.  Perhaps we can speed them up enough to obviate the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no right answer to this question. Up to a point, running parallel `SELECT` queries is (generally) going to be faster than one running query. Whether that point is 2 queries or 200 depends on the nature of the queries, the hardware configuration, the data, and the speeds of various components.

The situation becomes even more complex when you consider how many different users may be involved and whether or not the data is being updated. You can get into really bad situations with parallel queries and updates if the locks start cascading. Of course, this can happen with multiple simultaneous users as well.

My guess is that you want a throttling mechanism that will run, say, *n* queries at a time and put the rest into a queue.

Comment: I feared that "it depends" might be the answer. I ended up running a series of tests to see what actually happened in each case. I ended up going with queued queries because the overall time was a bit faster but, more importantly in my situation, the top of the page was loading way faster whereas before it was populating just based on whatever query was answered first.

Comment: @yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy . . . I would be very careful about "preferring parallelism" for your particular problem.  You need to be very careful about threads, memory, and concurrent sessions.